# miner shows 0x0000000... while getting block details using eth.getBlock()

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ethereumjs

I have created a private ethereum POA network using a bootnode and 6 nodes , of them 3 are miners .But every time i do a successful transaction over network , the miner returned by the getBlock of eth always returns 0x00.....as in Zero.
I have 3 nodes with geth running with different values ..(Eg:30311,8501).

`geth --identity "node1"  --datadir node1/ --syncmode 'full' --port 30311 --rpc --rpcaddr 'localhost' --rpcport 8501 --rpcapi 'personal,clique,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner,admin' --bootnodes 'enode://63ca0c0ab0bbc2edeb1ae3305a04fd4421d00a9ffdccf2bbde32b1f815f12dc535f04ddac885b708f6ef7e86dc3425a5feb1cd14290f4162311b79d7b28f8014@127.0.0.1:30310' --networkid 2134 --gasprice '1' -unlock '0' --password testpassword --rpccorsdomain "http://localhost:8000"` .

Similarly i have 3 miner nodes .

`geth --identity "miner1" --datadir miner1/ --syncmode 'full' --port 30314 --rpc --rpcaddr 'localhost' --rpcport 8504 --rpcapi 'personal,clique,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner,admin' --bootnodes 'enode://63ca0c0ab0bbc2edeb1ae3305a04fd4421d00a9ffdccf2bbde32b1f815f12dc535f04ddac885b708f6ef7e86dc3425a5feb1cd14290f4162311b79d7b28f8014@127.0.0.1:30310' --networkid 2134 --gasprice '1' --minerthreads=1 --mine --unlock '0' --password testpassword   --targetgaslimit 9000000000000` .

below is the genesis file .
`{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 2134,
    "homesteadBlock": 1,
    "eip150Block": 2,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip155Block": 3,
    "eip158Block": 3,
    "byzantiumBlock": 4,
    "clique": {
      "period": 1,
      "epoch": 30000
    }
  },
  "nonce": "0x0",
  "timestamp": "0x5b6164e8",
  "extraData": "0x48657920426c6f636b636861696e0000000000000000000000000000000000003598504e0c7e02a09ee4c9f73c8ba24ea20a1ec7659cbe27c34af47f922292ce1841213901b2f1ed976a7bbb8ee56f94c15ad1c26e90eaef1206a325dc64d2c492398df0afbf0a2410fc0630d16af8fb0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "gasLimit": "0x82F79CD9000",
  "difficulty": "0x1",
  "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "alloc": {
    "6b4326d6581e00b381cc9474c5ffcd189846f3e7": {
      "balance": "0x500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    }
  },
  "number": "0x0",
  "gasUsed": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}`

This is the snippet of the geth javascript console. 
`difficulty: 1,
  extraData: "0xd583010703846765746885676f312e39856c696e7578000000000000000000007238e232c2721215625eb047bf0b9ea5b0237d93d5660a51596676285fa1e66e28ea636d5ece29e834d76afb6719e55bf59b587099b1e4b5bb7f1d706937193f01",
  gasLimit: 9000000000000,
  gasUsed: 21000,
  hash: "0x9c373f78eddc19ebdc35ef609fb90e0fbf1011b90d20e9557a4139897bcf3b8f",
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  miner: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  mixHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  nonce: "0x0000000000000000",
  number: 35,
  parentHash: "0x7da1c1336edbb46558b4ca8831fcd2ba2479e1a65ead9a5323dda2cecd0a559b",
  receiptsRoot: "0x056b23fbba480696b65fe5a59b8f2148a1299103c4f57df839233af2cf4ca2d2",
  sha3Uncles: "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
  size: 720,
  stateRoot: "0x2dad5682e198ffebd54581d2e6b50b55c636e38fa9e6db151b1e060e9177130b",
  timestamp: 1533111402,
  totalDifficulty: 45,
  transactions: ["0x95e320145d266b8733255de7d071961f8a2e68329d3c6dd87526b4c5cf75d507"],
  transactionsRoot: "0xe6f998a8589d5a261ad3239f278f49e82ddc79496a42d910807e9d8ab225a7c1",
  uncles: []`

I followed the below link for setting up private ethereum network .
https://hackernoon.com/setup-your-own-private-proof-of-authority-ethereum-network-with-geth-9a0a3750cda8.

Apologies if i have missed some info.
Would appreciate if any one could help me with that :)..

GOT THE ANSWER FROM THIS POST :=> https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/15651